# Apache(XAMPP) not respond when high load

Tags: php, apache, xampp

My computer has 8 core and 16 GB RAM, in case of high traffic, my web server (apache - xampp) can't be accessed when the RAM hit 3GB. My CPU only used on 20%. And I need to restart the web server.

I set this on php.ini

```
max_execution_time=60
memory_limit=10128M
```

is there any suggestion to optimize my server, so that my server can serve till RAM/CPU used to it's limit?

---

edit:
my httpd-mpm.conf

```
#
# Server-Pool Management (MPM specific)
# 

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
#
# Note that this is the default PidFile for most MPMs.
#
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    PidFile "logs/httpd.pid"
</IfModule>

#
# Only one of the below sections will be relevant on your
# installed httpd.  Use "apachectl -l" to find out the
# active mpm.
#

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
#                         before terminating
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             5
    MinSpareServers          5
    MaxSpareServers         10
    MaxRequestWorkers      150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of worker threads
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
#                         before terminating
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers             2
    ServerLimit        500
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads         75 
    ThreadsPerChild         25
    MaxRequestWorkers      150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# event MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of worker threads
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
#                         before terminating
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers             2
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads         75
    ThreadsPerChild         25
    MaxRequestWorkers      150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# NetWare MPM
# ThreadStackSize: Stack size allocated for each worker thread
# StartThreads: Number of worker threads launched at server startup
# MinSpareThreads: Minimum number of idle threads, to handle request spikes
# MaxSpareThreads: Maximum number of idle threads
# MaxThreads: Maximum number of worker threads alive at the same time
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: Maximum  number of connections a thread serves. It
#                         is recommended that the default value of 0 be set
#                         for this directive on NetWare.  This will allow the
#                         thread to continue to service requests indefinitely.
<IfModule mpm_netware_module>
    ThreadStackSize      65536
    StartThreads           250
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads        250
    MaxThreads            1000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# OS/2 MPM
# StartServers: Number of server processes to maintain
# MinSpareThreads: Minimum number of idle threads per process, 
#                  to handle request spikes
# MaxSpareThreads: Maximum number of idle threads per process
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: Maximum number of connections per server process
<IfModule mpm_mpmt_os2_module>
    StartServers             2
    MinSpareThreads          5
    MaxSpareThreads         10
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# WinNT MPM
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in the server process
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild        1150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# The maximum number of free Kbytes that every allocator is allowed
# to hold without calling free(). In threaded MPMs, every thread has its own
# allocator. When not set, or when set to zero, the threshold will be set to
# unlimited.
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    MaxMemFree            2048
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_netware_module>
    MaxMemFree             100
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Check how many Apache workers you are set to. Consider asking this on serverfault instead :)

Comment: i add my httpd-mpm.conf. would you help me optimize it?

Comment: How about not running a high traffic site on XAMPP?

Comment: this was leftover project, I just continue to maintenance it. I'll consider this option.

Comment: XAMPP is for development, not really geared for production systems.  However, Apache, PHP, and MySQL can obviously be geared to run production systems fine, just off topic for Stackoverflow.  There are far too many things to check to cover in one question even if it weren't off topic.

Comment: What is the OS you are running XAMPP on?
Are you using 32-bit php.exe?

Comment: oracle linux 6, 64 bit

Comment: Do you see any errors or warning on launch of apache in apache logs?

Comment: there's no error message even in log file.

Comment: Are you getting server not responding from client side? What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the tweaks which you can add to your apache configuration file (httpd.conf) are

```
KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 75

KeepAliveTimeout 100

AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

Comment: i set MaxKeepAliveRequests 100 but KeepAliveTimeout 10, i'll try change it to 100